# Did this prediction come true on Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield, prophecy, inhumans

On *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, Coulson and his team encounter an Inhuman who can

> convey visions of the future to those he touches.

In S03E15, this Inhuman touches

> Malick, who sees a vision of himself dying, apparently directly at the hands of Hive.

Various visions have appeared to come true exactly as seen in several previous episodes.

However, in S03E17, it appears that

> Malick is killed by Skye, acting under Hive's influence.

So did the vision come true? Did it come only partly true? Was it wholly subverted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The Vision Came True**

Malik only *suspected* that it was Hive killing him. Everything we were shown happening in that vision happened. He died in horrible pain with blood all over his face.

**And Malik's Suspicion Basically Did**

Of course, Skye killed him under Hive's influence, so it's also essentially true that Hive killed him.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that is a good question and I didn't even remember that Malick

> saw his own death through that inhuman.

But I remember Malick

> telling Coulson that this going to be his last rodeo and he didn't think it would be with S.H.I.E.L.D.

So,

> Malick must have known that he was going to die by Hive's hand even though it was indirect.

I'd say it came partly true.

Comment: He discussed the vision with his daughter after Hive showed up at their home.